# How could i get the id of EditText from other layout in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm now on working with Google map of android studio and facing the problem that i cannot understand. I have 2 layout like below:

mani_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <EditText
              android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="9"
              android:backgroundTint="@color/Gray"
              android:gravity="start"
              android:hint="@string/search_hint"
              android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
              android:inputType="text"
              android:maxLines="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonSearch"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/search" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and map_fragment_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/framentGoogleMap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</fragment>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ic_gps"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/img"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_gps"
    android:visibility="visible" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And my app like this:

[image]

In edit text belong to main_activity.xml layout ? So is it possible in Fragment can access to The MainActivity to get the id of EditText box ?

Comment: What you try to achieve?

Comment: Are there any reason to get ID of edittext of Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it by using

```
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch)
```

This gives you the view which then you can convert it to any view you need like

```
if(view instanceof EditText) {
   editTextSearch = (EditText) view;
   //TODO do something with this
}
```

Developer docs: [Communicating with activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#CommunicatingWithActivity)

Comment: Thanks Anand, when I did that only worked for the Map tab and the Places tab it didn't work for this button.